# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS - Is it the case to enable or install a firewall?

Tags: firewall

I have an old Acer Aspire One AOA150/ZG5,with only 1 Gb of RAM.I have a firewall already enabled on my router.

I read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall and much more about security.

I'd like to have an opinion,considering I'm using an old and weak computer, if it's the case to enable or install a firewall.That I've never used before.

If,yes, will a firewall slow down my connection speed that is only 40+ (wireless)?

Which of the three solutions,described in the link above,would be recommended ? and,especially,because I'm not an expert,the settings described are OK?

Thank you

Comment: You are asking for an opinion, you will get some who say yes, some who say no. What would you use it for ?

Comment: @Panther,thank you for your answer and your beautiful post "Ubuntu Security".Mainly to surf the internet.

Comment: You can use ice. `sudo ufw enable` it will not affect performance.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: @Panther,is it enough only enable without any other settings?Thank you

Comment: Yes, the default rules are sufficient for most, if not all, end (home) users.

Comment: @Panther,thank you for your advice.Now I have the firewall enabled on the router and UFW,is it correct to keep both enabled?

Comment: I would use both

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it depends on various factors.

For home purpose, and not many devices around it would be decent choice. I've even ran Raspberries for this purpose on about couple of months, and didn't notice degradation of speed.
When building a firewall, most relevant components are quality Network Interface Card (NIC) and good CPU.

As all packets drive to nic, then to kernel, having lot of rules, means kernel would need slightly more time to process those. Also, since you're planning Ubuntu, I would recommend you to go with learning of `iptables` , even thou ufw and other iptables frontends are kinda .. simpler for start.

However, for home purpose, it would be barely unnoticeable.
Those are my 2 cents. Good luck.